# how to generate dynamic rows of a table based on input from textbox

Tags: angular, angular6

I am working on a issue, where I need to generate dynamic rows of a table based on the input given by user through textbox.

My .ts code:

```js
start(val){
    this.printVal=val;
    console.log('Value of start is',this.printVal);
    return new Array(val);
  }
```

.html code:

```html
<div class="container col-lg-12">
  <input type="number" #data> &nbsp; 
  <button (click)="start(data.value)">Start</button>
  <br><br>
  <table>
    <ng-container >
<tr *ngFor="let item of [].constructor(printVal); let i = index"> //If instead of printVal, I give a number then it prints the desired output

  <td>{{i}}</td>

</tr>
    </ng-container>
  </table>
</div>
```

Actually i need to create a table like this

```
 | Input|sec|Multipilcation
 |------|---|------------------------------
 |10    |1  |10
 |10    |2  |20
 |10    |3  |30
 |10    |4  |40
 .
 .
 .
 10    |10  |100
```

Where 10 is the number provided through input box, after each second a row should get add and it value should get print and third column in multiplication of both and the table row should get continue till the input value provided.

Please, suggest me what I am doing wrong and how can I print dynamic rows based on the input provided.

Comment: `*ngFor="let item of [].constructor(printVal); let i = index"` Why ?

Comment: because i need to iterate on numbers, i found this solution on net

Comment: I am getting a number from input box and i need to iterate till the number provided and need to create number of rows based on the input provided

Comment: not use printVal, use data.value (the reference variable you use in your input)

Comment: i tried that too, it is also not working

Comment: First issue, you're using a syntax you don't know and don't understand. 

Second issue, you're not assigning your value to anything. 

Third issue, you have no data persistence.

I'm sorry, but it seems you didn't even try, you just copy-pasted some random code to crate a question, and you expect us to do it for you ... [Have you opened the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngforof) ?

Comment: Hello. Please take a look at this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxuvcc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: hey, thanks for a pointer, I got what I was doing wrong.. thank you :)

Comment: @trichetriche may be I have putted up the question wrongly, I was not getting how to iterate a loop on number. For this I tried some solutions. And the solution which I mentioned in my question  was working for me when i give it a number as input. But, yes i didn't get into the depth of its syntax, so may be that's why it created a wrong impression on you. I'll take care of it going forward.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printVal` is an string variable, so when you are creating a new array like this:

```
[].constructor(printVal)
```

you will get for example `[].constructor("3")` so it is an array with one element.

You should cast value from input to number:

```
this.printVal = +val;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out, what I was doing wrong. Since morning I was working on it. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following code. Maybe it will give you an idea to achieve your goal.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  { 
  printVal=[0,3,5,6,7];
  
  start(val){
    this.printVal.push=val;
    console.log('Value of start is',this.printVal);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container col-lg-12">
 <input type="number" #data> &nbsp; 
  <button (click)="start(data.value)">Start</button>
  <br><br>
  <ng-container >
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th>Second</th>
      <th>Multiplication</th>
    </tr>
    
<tr *ngFor="let item of printVal; let i = index"> 
 <td>{{printVal.length}}</td>
  <td>{{i}}</td>
   <td>{{item*i}}</td>
</tr>
  </table>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```